# yum-config-manager --enable repo id but not work

Tags: centos, yum

### Description:

I tried to use `yum repolist all` to get all my repos and i got

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.tds.net
repo id                                                        repo name
docker-ce-nightly/7/x86_64                                     Docker CE Nightly - x86_64                                                        disabled
docker-ce-nightly-debuginfo/7/x86_64                           Docker CE Nightly - Debuginfo x86_64                                              disabled
docker-ce-nightly-source/7                                     Docker CE Nightly - Sources                                                       disabled
docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64                                      Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                         disabled
docker-ce-stable-debuginfo/7/x86_64                            Docker CE Stable - Debuginfo x86_64                                               enabled:       17
docker-ce-stable-source/7                                      Docker CE Stable - Sources                                                        enabled:        0
docker-ce-test/7/x86_64                                        Docker CE Test - x86_64                                                           disabled
docker-ce-test-debuginfo/7/x86_64                              Docker CE Test - Debuginfo x86_64                                                 disabled
docker-ce-test-source/7                                        Docker CE Test - Sources                                                          disabled
```

I was trying to enable repo with repo id `docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64` by  `yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64` but failed with below info

```
[root@slc07ppm02 xiaojguan]# yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
```

But I am able to add repo by `yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-stable\*` but the repo id `docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64` which should be ok.

### Expected help:

Am i able to add repo with id `docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64` by type below command:

```
yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `yum repolist` shows that the repo that you want, `docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64`, is already enabled. What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've changed the output to the original.

Comment: The output still shows that the repo is enabled. There is nothing indicating that what you did didn't work.

Comment: No, `docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64                                      Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                         disabled` shows it was disabled.

Comment: I understand. Does it work if you remove those Docker CE repos and add this one: `yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo`?

Comment: This worked, but this will have no help on this problem ',:-l.

Comment: It provides the same docker packages.

Comment: Yes, maybe i wasn't expressing my question clearly, i wonder why `yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64` not work as `  docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64` is the repo id.

Comment: From the error message `Failed to set locale, defaulting to C`, maybe there's something with your local that's not recognizing certain characters in the repo name. Add the output of the command `locale` to your question.